# How to change main content when sidebar item is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

Browsing stackoverflow, I see this as a very popular topic using various IDEs but none suitable to my needs.

I am working on a single page app (using: html, javascript, css) that has several files: `main content`, `main header`, `main footer`, `index`, `stlye`, `top`, `side`. 
`Main content` will display content depending on which item is clicked in the sidebar, `side` and the sidebar list depends on which topbar item is clicked from `top`

Selecting a topbar element and displaying the proper sidebar is working fine but after this step, how do I get different info into the main content depending on which sidebar item is clicked

An example of the sidebar functionality is here: http://balloob.github.io/react-sidebar/example/responsive_example.html

so if I were to click on `Mock menu item 0`, certain content will load to the main stage
if `Mock menu item 1`, different content loads. 
.
.
.
if `Mock menu item n`, nth content loads

I want to display html tables on the main stage when I can click on a sidebar item

I have tried the following code by placing it in the `main content` file:

```
<script>
function showContent() {
var x = document.getElementById("table");
if (x.style.display === "none") {
x.style.display = "block";
} else {
x.style.display = "none";
}
}
</script>
```

and then calling the function from `side` as below:

`<div id="CV" class="dynamic-content"><li onclick="showContent()" class="side-bar-item"><a class="side-link" href="website_name">LINK</a></li></div>`

This only creates a blank page named `website_name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, because you have a link to `website_name`.

You should set the `onclick` event in the `<a>` element. And even then, you'll need to stop the default action, navigating to the link's `href`.

HTML:

```
<div id="CV" class="dynamic-content">
  <li class="side-bar-item">
    <a class="side-link" href="#" onclick="showContent(event)">LINK</a>
  </li>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function showContent(ev) {
  (ev||event).preventDefault();
  ...the rest of the function
}
```

When you use the `onlick` attribute, you should send `event` as *one of the params* (it doesn't have to be the first one, it depends on your function's params) to use `preventDefault()` as shown, that's the *crossbrowser* way (Chrome and Firefox behave differently there).